# Converting float to date and time

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert float number into date and time I've tried many things

**df[time]**

[image]

`df1['time']=  datetime.fromtimestamp(df1['time']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")`

`df1['time']= datetime.strptime(df1['time'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")`

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: What is the original data?  I cannot guess what "3854.71" is supposed to represent.  If that's days, that's about 10 years, which doesn't correspond to any epoch I know.

Comment: you're passing a series (e.g. `df['time']`) to a function that takes a single value (e.g. `datetime.fromtimestamp`)

Comment: "I need to convert float number into date and time" In your own words, if the data for one of the cells is (as in the example you showed) `3854.71`, **what should the resulting date and time be, and why**? What rule do you want to use for the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

To convert float to date and time, you can use the following method:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df_example = pd.DataFrame({
    'exampleName': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],   
    'time': [3854.71, 3854.71, 3854.71, 3854.118, 3854.118, 3854.118, 3859.503]
})

df_example['time'] = df_example['time'].map(lambda x: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(x)))

print(df_example['time'])
```

**Output**

```
0    1970-01-01 09:04:14
1    1970-01-01 09:04:14
2    1970-01-01 09:04:14
3    1970-01-01 09:04:14
4    1970-01-01 09:04:14
5    1970-01-01 09:04:14
6    1970-01-01 09:04:19
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea if the resulting time values are valid but you can convert the float numbers to a datetime stamp using the following:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Using the above statement you can convert:

```
    Time
0   3854.710
1   3858.118
2   3859.503
```

into:

```
    Time
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000003854
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000003858
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000003859
```

Comment: That seems extremely unlikely to be the dates they're expecting.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree, but OP ask to convert float number to datetime value without the context of a source or desired epoch reference. Hence, my starting comment, concerning the validity of the resulting values.